# <div id= ??> What other types of ids can be used when making a webpage?

Tags: html, css

I've noticed that the webpage for html/css has this  ... and id=menu / content / footer.

I am wondering if there are any others? Also, if there are, which ones do they have?

Can i create some on my own? if possible, how?

Comment: You can also do `<div id="ThisIsOneOfTheNonSenseIdsYouCanAlsoHave1234567890">`

Comment: use some notepad++, create a new file say index.html and then create your own divs with your own hand picked mind boggling ids.

Comment: So its possibble to use any kind of naming convention? and it'll still make a div for me to use?

Comment: Yes. The `id` is just a way to get a precise element in your JavaScript code, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create any `id` name you like.

These

```
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
<div id='content'></div>
<div id='this-is-a-div'></div>
```

are all possible `id` names.

`id`s are used to **uniquely** identify a tag/element. An example might be a boy named Tom. The `div` in this case would be that he's human, the `id` "Tom", and a possible `class` "boy". A `class` is used to describe multiple properties of an object (much like `id`s are), however you can apply them to multiple tags/elements.

As suggested by others, you can use `data-*` (where `*` is anything you like) to also identify multiple elements at once. You can read more on the `data-*` feature [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

If you're looking to create different `div` elements (or tags), its strongly recommended not to. You can see a full list of all HTML5 tags/elements on Mozilla's Developer [website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/HTML5_element_list).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any name id. Then if you want to design, the assignment of names to id's, you can use it in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can create of your own by calling them `data-*`, `*` being what you want.

If you are using jQuery, you can get  what is in this parameter using `.data()` : http://api.jquery.com/data/

You can find the paremeters you can set by tag in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/. As you can see there is a lot, but you probalby won't have to use them all.

Comment: This is a very complete site, what's wrong about it?

Comment: mmmm.....it advises on old semantics, its PHP tutorials are completely open to hack and its no where near to w3 standards, but still call it w3schools...tried its PHP tutorials once!  :)

Comment: I'm cuurrently using html/css only, annd im restricted to IE 8, my choicies are limited. will there be a difference if i used your approach on an old browser?

Comment: @NoobEditor Thanks for that precisions, I didn't know. Though, I think it's a good base to begin with.

Comment: @user3765954 This is an HTML5 convention.

Comment: @user3765954 : mate, if you are limited to IE, forget new things/tags and stick to old school of `class` and `id`s :)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is like a name for that element. Instead of using id, use `class` for styling purposes, and html5 `data-somevalue` attribute for javascript hooks.

Comment: What if im using html? the older versions, im restricted by trying to make it work on IE 8 :/ is there a diifference?

Comment: No, you are not restricted, just make sure your html doctype is set to support html5(`!DOCTYPE="html"`), or if you need to be something else, just use `id`, there's nothing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute specifies a unique identifier for an element, and it is something that the author of an HTML document chooses. No value has any predefined meaning. The formal rules vary by HTML version, but the only real restriction in browsers is that the `id` attribute value must be nonempty and must not contain space characters. Otherwise, it’s all up to you.

If you have noticed that values like `menu`, `content`, `footer` are frequently used, it’s just because authors have made similar decisions, reflecting some common constituents of web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any `id` you'd like, on any tag element. The attribute `id` is a GLOBAL attribute. This means that all HTML tags supports the attribute id.

For HTML, ID's are case insensitive. That might not be the case for JavaScript or other languages.
ID's have some limitations as far as what characters you can use:

- Must contain at least one character
- Must not contain any space characters

**Documentation:**

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_standardattributes.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

On a quick note, it is best to use the new HTML5 tags (`<header>`, `<nav>`, `<main>`, `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`) to divide/organize your web page, instead of just `<div>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...head content
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    ...header content
    </header>

    <nav>
    ...nav menu
    </nav>

    <main>
        <section id="news">
            <article id="who-let-the-dog-out">
            ...article content
            </article>

            <article id="LottoSurprice">
            ...article content
            </article>
        </section>

        <section id="blog">
        ...section content
        </section>

        <aside id="advertisement">
        ...aside content
        </aside>
    </main>  <!-- end of page content -->

    <footer>
    ...footer content
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see with this example, it makes much more sense. It's easier to read and debug. It's the new HTML5 goodness. Much better than `<div id="menu">`, `<div id="content">`, `<div id="footer">`